# Disable/Enable specific static text control?

Tags: mfc, dialog, visual-studio-2015

I have this `STATIC` text control on my **dialog**:

[image: Static Text control]

Now, I know that I can rename the control to something like `IDC_STATIC_STYLE`, and then I could either map it to a `CStatic` object and disable/enable that way, or I could compare a `CWnd::GetDlgCtrlID` against it and go that route.

My issue here is that I am seeing if I can **avoid** renaming the control (and thus not affecting the existing translations in my resource DLL files). Is there any other way to locate this specific control? I note that in the the IDE it has a grey out entry for **(Name)** saying **IDC_STATIC51**.

If I have to, I will rename it, but if I use it as it is, I all interested!

Thank you!

Comment: The only way to identify that control in a resource file would be in the dialog resource where it is declared. By default, all static controls have the ID `IDC_STATIC`, which is #defined to -1. It is not unique, so there's no way for you to provide a unique caption for that control outside of its original definition. Therefore, you can give the control a new custom ID without affecting your translations. Z order, as xMRi suggested, will work, but it's somewhat more fragile. (Also note that if the "Simple" style is set, a static control will not paint any differently when disabled.)

Comment: Using appTranslator you do not need to specifically name any IDC_STATIC objects to specific names. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The name in the UI is just an internal ID and has no connection to the resource.
2. Just use the Z-Order (if it is defined correctly). That is the way to do it in some cases. Just determine the control with the input (in your case the combo box), and then use [`GetWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms633515(v=vs.85).aspx), with `GW_HWNDPREV`. And you have the handle of the window preceding your combo box.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the better way to get a handle of the static control given its text is:

```
HWND hStyle = ::FindWindowEx(m_hWnd, 0, 0, L"Style");
::SetWindowText(hStyle, L"This is a test");
```

Comment: I see. But, this does not help when you are using a localized resource DLL and thus the annotation will be different at run time dependant on language in use.

Answer (score -1):

refer to [this](https://www.programmersought.com/article/58805487962/)

```
BOOL CALLBACK CTab_indexDlg::DisableControl(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    BOOL disableAllControls = (BOOL)lParam;
    char className[256];
    ::GetClassName(hwnd, className, 256);
    TRACE("%s\n", className);

    if ((FALSE == disableAllControls)
        && ((_stricmp(className, "Edit") == 0) || (_stricmp(className, "Button") == 0))) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    ::EnableWindow(hwnd, FALSE);
    return TRUE;
}

void CTab_indexDlg::DisableAllControls()
{
    ::EnumChildWindows(m_hWnd, &CTab_indexDlg::DisableControl, (LPARAM)m_bDisableAllControls);

    GetDlgItem(IDCANCEL)->EnableWindow(TRUE);
    GetDlgItem(IDOK)->EnableWindow(TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think think this answers the question. Using the above code you can't disable a specific `IDSTATIC` control on the window.